# Upgrading Motherboard and processor

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, intel-core-i7, cpu

I am upgrading my motherboard (ASUS M2NPV-MX) to (ASUS Rampage III) and processor AMD X2 Dual Core to Intel Core i7-980x. I was wondering after upgrading these hardwares will windows bootup fine? If not what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Windows should bootup fine.  If you have installed any third party chipset drivers that came with the previous motherboard, it's recommended that you uninstall them first.

Comment: From where you read it? or is it your personal experience?

Comment: It's my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you from the recent experience with XP that it didn't worked at first, but REPAIR started from the boot disk did its job, and left me with usable XP.

Rummors are that 7 will live through such upgrade without any problems.

Comment: I had a problem with windows 7 in past I was unable to upgrade from console. I want to confirm if this really works.